# Insertion sort worst case

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Why is the worst case for insertion sort n^2? Can it be nlogn with binary search? Minimize the location search to log(n) and then use a low level function like memmove to minimize swaps?

Comment: The reason that insertion sort is O(n^2) is that worst case you need to move `n` items `n` times. Using `memmove` to move the items doesn't change the time complexity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this better fits in  [\[ programmers se \]](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If you make any of the modifications you describe in your question, it's not an insertion sort anymore.

Comment: @sjsam: That's not really a valid close reason.  It has to be off-topic on Stack Overflow first.

Comment: I fail to see how memmove keeps n swaps? You have n time going through the array. Then log n time searching for the elements spot. Then constant moving the block of memory with memmove. Making it n log n.

Comment: I do think Robert Harvey answered the question though, thank you.

Comment: Assume it takes zero time to find where to insert an element, and assume worst case, that each time that element belongs in the front (like a reverse ordered array). That's reading 1 element, shifting n-1 elements, then storing 1 element, which is done n times for n^2 read/write operations.

Comment: @Taztingo The assumption that `memmove` takes constant time is false. It is more accurate to assume it takes time proportional to number of bytes it has to move.

Comment: @Taztingo memmove() is not constant time. It's just a customized O(n) loop. If you like, go find any of the clib implementations and verify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect Worst-case time complexity of Insertion Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980328/incorrect-worst-case-time-complexity-of-insertion-sort)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Can it be nlogn with binary search?**

You will need to sort the array first to use binary search, as binary search is only possible in sorted array

**Edit**
Even if the first part of the array is sorted. The case now is that, you find the position to insert in logn steps. Then You actually need to insert the value there. For that you will need to move all the elements to right requiring n steps at worst case.

Comment: Insertion sort builds up a sorted part of the array, one element at a time. A modified insertion sort could use binary search (rather than linear scan) to find the insertion point for a new element, and this is what @Taztingo is suggesting.